# What was the first mechanical Turing-complete machine ever constructed?

Tags: history, computer-architecture, turing-completeness

We know that Charles Babbage *designed* the first Turing-complete mechanical machine - the [Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_Engine) - in the 1800s, but it was never actually *built* (not [yet](http://plan28.org/) anyway).

In recent history, [at least one](http://hackaday.com/2011/03/25/mechanical-turing-machine-can-compute-anything-slowly/) mechanical Turing machine **has** been built.  (This example is in fact a [U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine)niversal Turing Machine, albeit with finite storage space.) But was this the first one, or are there earlier examples?

What was the first mechanical Turing-complete machine constructed, who built it and when?

---

Edit: By mechanical, I mean no electronics are used.

Comment: I don't think that before WW2, Turing considered building a *mechanical* Turing machine. IMHO, Turing machine was then a theoretical construction. Building one mechanically is fun, but is not efficient. Mechanical computing machines existed since Pascal (XVIIth century, France) and where more efficient doing useful computations (additions & multiplications ...)

Comment: Nobody wanted that. Tabulators were for the accounting and censuses, analog devices solved differential equations and were better as gun/bomb/torpedo sights (cheaper and smaller).

Comment: The first working freely programmable computer was maybe [Konrad Zuse's Z1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z1_(computer))

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that [Jim MacArthur's machine](https://hackaday.com/2011/03/25/mechanical-turing-machine-can-compute-anything-slowly/) (mentioned in the question) is in fact the first.

Here are the contenders I am aware of:

**[The Analytical Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_engine)**. As joeytwiddle points out, it has not yet been implemented.

**[Konrad Zuse's Z1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z1_(computer)).** It had I/O, memory, and an arithmetic unit, but it [did not have branching](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1886). So, not Turing complete.

**[Relay-based machines](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/why-were-relays-prevalent-in-early-1940s-computers-when-vacuum-tubes-were-also-a)**. The linked SE question lists a number of computers that, it says, were mainly relay-based. You could say these were not electronic, but rather electromechanical. They are full-fledged computers, but I am inclined not to count them as fully mechanical.

In 1978, Danny Hillis and Bryan Silverman designed and built a **[tic-tac-toe-playing machine made from Tinkertoys](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/X39.81)**. But it was not fully programmable, being more an encoding of the full game tree of tic-tac-toe.

It should be possible to construct a machine that runs under steam power (or is fully belt-driven anyway with no internal electricity required), uses punch cards for bulk storage, and can do general computer tasks like calculation and text processing. But it would be a significant endeavor and would get a lot of publicity. The Analytical Engine is a bit like that. I think a project to make something even fancier would be an unlikely boondoggle.

All of that said, I was not familiar with MacArthur's machine until I read this question, so it's possible another hobbyist has beaten MarArthur to the punch.